# extension to an ultrafilter

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let X be a topological space. How to show a filter T on X can be extended to a unique ultrafilter on X iff T is an ultrafilter.
All I know is that every filter can be extended to an ultrafilter. I think this can be useful here. But I cannot find the link.
Any help would be aporeciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes u r right.thanks .

Comment: What does the topology have to do with it? You're not talking about "open ultrafilters" or anything like that, right? Just plain set-theoretic ultrafilters?

Comment: I suppose you know that an ultrafilter can't be extended to another ultrafilter, right? So only one direction needs proof: if a filter $T$ can be extended to a unique ultrafilter, then $T$ is already an ultrafilter. Or to put it more simply, if a filter $T$ is not an ultrafilter, then it can be extended to an ultrafilter in more than one way.

Comment: Yes ypu r right

Comment: Why more than one way?

Comment: Hint: if the filter $T$ is not an ultrafilter, then there is a set $A\subset X$ such that $A\notin T$ and $X\setminus A\notin T.$ Then $T\cup\{A\}$ can be extended to a filter $T_1$ which can be extended to an ultrafilter $U_1.$ Likewise $T\cup\{X\setminus A\}$ can be extended to a filter $T_2$ which can be extended to an ultrafilter $U_2.$ Clearly $U_1\ne U_2.$

Comment: Does T U{A } has f.i.p?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61049/discussion-between-math-is-fun-and-bof).

Comment: I don't do chat, and this is not a discussion. I gave you some good hints. Use them.

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is this:

> If $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter on $X$, and $A \subset X$ is such that both $A \notin \mathcal{F}$ *and* $X\setminus A \notin \mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F} \cup \{A\}$ has the finite intersection property.

The proof is simple: suppose not. Then there are finitely many sets of $\mathcal{F} \cup \{A\}$ that have empty intersection. As $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under finite intersections, this can only happen if there is some $F_1 \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $F_1 \cap A = \emptyset$. But this is equivalent to $F_1 \subseteq X\setminus A$, which implies (by the enlargement axiom for filters) that $X\setminus A \in \mathcal{F}$, quod non. This contradiction shows that $\mathcal{F} \cup \{A\}$ has the fip, so can be extended to a filter $\mathcal{F}_A$ which can be explicitly defined as $$\mathcal{F}_A := \{B \subseteq X: \exists F \in \mathcal{F}: F \cap A \subseteq B\}$$

One easily shows this is a filter on $X$ that contains $A$ and all of $\mathcal{F}$.

So if for some filter $\mathcal{F}$ we have that there is some set $A$ such that neither $A$ nor $A^c = X\setminus A$ are not in $\mathcal{F}$, we can also apply the above idea (by symmetry) to get a filter $\mathcal{F}_{A^c}$ that properly extends $\mathcal{F}$ and then $\mathcal{F}_{A^c}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{A}$ are distinct (one contains $A$, the other does not) proper extensions of $\mathcal{F}$. We can extend both of them to ultrafilters, that are thus also distinct.

We conclude by contraposition that if $\mathcal{F}$ has a unique ultrafilter extension, then for all sets $A \subseteq X$, either $A \in \mathcal{F}$ or $X\setminus A \in \mathcal{F}$, and this property characterises ultrafilters (which follows from the observation that if $\mathcal{G} \supsetneq \mathcal{F}$ for some filter, any $B \in \mathcal{G}\setminus \mathcal{F}$ will fail this criterion, as $B$ is not in $\mathcal{F}$ and $X\setminus B$ isn't either (or it would be in $\mathcal{G}$ which cannot be)).

Answer (score -1):

If T is not an ultrafilter, then there is some A subset X with
A not in T and X - A not in T.  Thus T can be extended to an
ultrafilter F with A in F and to an ultrafilter G with X - A in G.